# Dynamically setting bucket time-to-live on Riak and Bitcask with riak-js

Tags: node.js, riak, riak-js

Is it possible to change the `expiry_secs` parameter on bitcask buckets dynamically? Calling `riak.saveBucket('bucket', {expiry_secs: 60});` will cause subsequent calls of `riak.getBucket('bucket')` to report 60 as the key ttl, but keys never seem to expire.

Is there a separate setting that needs to be modified, or can `expiry_secs` only be set in Riak's `app.config` and not from a client application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Bitcask handles expiry at the backend level, not the bucket level.  When Riak starts, each Bitcask backend reads the current `expiry_secs` from the application environment and stores it in its internal state.  While you can change the setting using the `set_env` function, the backends would not recognize that until something caused them to restart.